# Python: Why is adding dict values per key dependent on order?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose you have several dictionaries that keep track of three float values per key (in a sub-dict). You want to be able to merge these dictionaries in a way that adds the values of keys that exist in multiple dicts.

With an ordinary dict update, values are overwritten, so you subclass `dict()`:

```
class StatementDict(dict):
    def add(self, statement):
        ann_id = statement[0]
        lvl_dict = statement[1]
        if ann_id in self:
            self[ann_id]['skill'] += lvl_dict['skill']
            self[ann_id]['knowledge'] += lvl_dict['knowledge']
            self[ann_id]['interest'] += lvl_dict['interest']
        else:
            self[ann_id] = lvl_dict

    def update(self, statement_dict):
        for statement in statement_dict.iteritems():
            self.add(statement)
```

Then you place the dicts you would like to merge/add into an ordinary dict's keys:

```
# Small example data that reproduces the error
few_statements = {}
few_statements['linkedin'] = {u'Homerun': {u'skill': 14.0,
                                           u'knowledge': 34.0,
                                           u'interest': 20.0}}
few_statements['tudelft'] = {u'Presentation': {u'skill': 14.0,
                                               u'knowledge': 34.0,
                                               u'interest': 20.0},
                             u'Future': {u'skill': 16.0,
                                         u'knowledge': 25.33,
                                         u'interest': 2.0},
                             u'Visual_perception': {u'skill': 20.46,
                                                    u'knowledge': 28.35,
                                                    u'interest': 4.0}}
few_statements['website'] = {u'Homerun': {u'skill': 1.0,
                                          u'knowledge': 3.0,
                                          u'interest': 2.0}}

few_statements['shareworks'] = {u'Presentation': {u'skill': 8.0,
                                                  u'knowledge': 20.0,
                                                  u'interest': 12.0},
                                u'Future': {u'skill': 17.0,
                                            u'knowledge': 26.33,
                                            u'interest': 3.0},
                                u'Visual_perception': {u'skill': 2.0,
                                                       u'knowledge': 3.0,
                                                       u'interest': 6.0}}
```

Now we should be able to add these key, value pairs to a `StatementDict()` one-by-one, or use the `StatementDict.update()` method. The order in which the source dicts are added to the StatementDict should not matter for the outcome.

```
# First we try updating in one order
small_test1a = StatementDict()
for origin in ("tudelft", "website", "linkedin", "shareworks"):
    for st in few_statements[origin].iteritems():
        small_test1a.add(st)

# And then in another order
small_test2 = StatementDict()
for origin in ("linkedin", "shareworks", "tudelft", "website"):
    for st in few_statements[origin].iteritems():
        small_test2.add(st)

print "Different order, same result?", small_test1a == small_test2
                                                # False, but why?
for key in small_test1a:
    print "Desired:", key, small_test1a[key]
    print "Unexpected:", key, small_test2[key]
```

Alas, the order in which dicts are added does influence the outcome. But why, and what has happened with the unexpected outcome?

```
Desired: Future {u'skill': 33.0, u'knowledge': 51.66, u'interest': 5.0}
Unexpected: Future {u'skill': 50.0, u'knowledge': 77.99, u'interest': 8.0}
Desired: Presentation {u'skill': 22.0, u'knowledge': 54.0, u'interest': 32.0}
Unexpected: Presentation {u'skill': 30.0, u'knowledge': 74.0, u'interest': 44.0}
Desired: Homerun {u'skill': 15.0, u'knowledge': 37.0, u'interest': 22.0}
Unexpected: Homerun {u'skill': 29.0, u'knowledge': 71.0, u'interest': 42.0}
Desired: Visual_perception {u'skill': 22.46, u'knowledge': 31.35, u'interest': 10.0}
Unexpected: Visual_perception {u'skill': 24.46, u'knowledge': 34.35, u'interest': 16.0}
```

Adding the dicts in the second order seems to double the values (adds them twice?) of the dict that was placed first. I don't understand why this happens. How do I get the desired addition behavior to occur reliably, independent of the order of addition?

Another thing I don't understand: why do the values of `small_test1a` change when I make a new `StatementDict()` and fill it with the same values?

Running the following lines causes `small_test1a` to change in the final iteration of the loop:

```
small_test1b = StatementDict()
for origin in ("tudelft", "website", "linkedin", "shareworks"):
    small_test1b.update(few_statements[origin])
print "\nDoes .update() function?", small_test1a == small_test1b
print small_test1a
```

P.S. Using my actual data, no addition happens at all. Instead, the first placed values are kept. This is **not** the same as updating an ordinary dict, where values are overwritten. Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce this behavior with small test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
self[ann_id] = lvl_dict
```

you make `self[ann_id]` another name for that particular dictionary (e.g., the one for "tudelft").  Then, when you do a subsequent:

```
self[ann_id]['skill'] += lvl_dict['skill']
```

you modify the previous `lvl_dict` based on the current one (i.e., in this case, change the one for "tudelft" based on the one for "website").

A minimal fix for this is to [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html?highlight=copy.copy#copy.copy) the first dictionary.  However, I might try working with `collections.defaultdict`, so that you can eliminate the `if ann_id in self:` test entirely.  When defaultdict creates a new dictionary it will be a new instance and hence not modify any existing one.

---

An example using `defaultdict` and the lambda function in your comment below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class StatementDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        defaultdict.__init__(self,
            lambda: {'skill': 0.0, 'knowledge': 0.0, 'interest': 0.0})

    def add(self, statement):
        ... as before ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to copy! I've made this mistake several times before with dictionaries, so I'm a bit disappointed in myself for not having caught on by now.

Working with `collections.defaultdict` however seems less straightforward. I tried to subclass it as `StatementDict(defaultdict(lvl_dict_factory))`, where `lvl_dict_factory = lambda: {'skill': 0.0, 'knowledge': 0.0, 'interest':0.0}`, but that's apparently not how it's done.

Comment: Ah, that's the wrong way to invoke it.  If you have `class StatementDict(defaultdict)` you create an instance with, e.g., `small_test1a = StatementDict(lvl_dict_factory)`.  Or, provide your own `__init__`, which might look/feel cleaner to you; I'll edit in an example.